# Super-slow LAN speed, unless downloading through Chrome's FTP client

Tags: ftp, chrome, vsftpd, lan

I have connected 2 PCs using ethernet cable and set up FTP on one of them to transfer some >100GB of files. However, trying to download it, I run into a problem of speed not more than 50kB/s. It happens whether I download through Nautilus or Filezilla.

However, if I try to download a large file using Google Chrome, it downloads at speed around 50MB/s, which is pretty good. But Chrome cannot download directories.

What can be a solution to either speed up LAN or download a directory through Chrome?

- UPD: I tried to create a torrent and send it that way, but it's no better, stays around 100kB/s...
- UPD1: I changed the cable and it didn't change, also it stops completely, if I turn on WiFi parallel to the cable.
- UPD2: I found an advise to edit `/etc/default/grub` to disable IPv6, but it didn't help as well.

A small detail: both sender and receiver file systems are NTFS, does it make a difference?

Comment: Ethernet uses a pair to transmit and a pair to receive. As you are using a crossover cable to connect two PCs back to back you can set full-duplex on both interfaces and check if this give you more throughput.

Comment: @jcbermu I used ethtool to change it, so the command was `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full`, but it didn't help again...

Comment: The question might be off-topic only because it's related more to networks than to unix. But the problem wasn't solved using a typo and the answer might be useful for other people, because after much googling I haven't found anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The problem was far not in the connection, it is in the file system. I was trying to copy from NTFS to NTFS. When I formatted the receiving FS to ext4, speed increased to 40+MB/sec.